# Transcoding UTF8 to ASCII does not work if string is read from file

Tags: c#, utf-8, ascii

I am reading a string that is partially encoded in UTF8. By partially I mean that some characters that have ASCII equivalent are using the ascii equivalent, but others use \u00 encoding. Lets take this example:

```
  string utfString = "\u003Cdiv class=\'_footer\'>";
```

`\u003C` is equivalent to `<`, but `>` is encoded in ASCII. I am not sure why the api returns such mixed results. `Content-Type Charset` is indeed specified as `utf-8`.

If I try to transcode to ASCII, with this code, I get correct result:

```
    string utfString = "\u003Cdiv class=\'_footer\'>";
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utfString);
    string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(utf8Bytes); // <div class='_footer'>
```

On the other hand, If I read this from file, I never get the ASCII version of it:

```
  using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\ansi-uft8.txt"))
  using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fs,Encoding.UTF8)){

    string utfString = tr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(utfString); // prints \u003Cdiv class=\'_footer\'>
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling this has something to do with how the file was saved. I saved is both as ANSI and UTF-8 and still got the same result. My main goal is to fransform all characters that have ascii equivalent to ascii, and leave everything else in utf8 form.

Comment: There's no such thing as ASCII transcoding. The characters in the 0x00-07F range in UTF8 are *identical* to ASCII by design. All strings in .NET are Unicode so `utfString` is nothing special, in fact it's just `<div class='_footer\>`. There's no need to use that escape sequence

Comment: The only way for `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` to return individual escape sequence characters, is to *save* them this way. Instead of saving `<`, to save `\`, `u`, `0`, `0` etc. How was this file created?

Comment: To put it another way, if there was such a problem, ASP.NET itself wouldn't work because all HTML tags start with `<`. This SO page wouldn't work - SO is an ASP.NET site. Finally, if you try `Debug.Assert(utfString==asciiString);` you'll see that the `asciiString` isn't. It's identical tto the original string

Comment: Thanks. This is a response copy pasted from Chrome Dev Tools. Could Chrome mess the displaying of data?

Comment: When I created the file,  I pasted the response in.

Comment: No, Chrome won't mess with data. Where did this response come from, where was it contained? If that string was contained in HTML or XML, it would have to be encoded, just not *this* way.

Comment: In the first snippet you have the C# compiler interpreting `\u003c` as a standard escape sequence in a string literal, trivially producing `<`. In the second snippet you actually read what is in the file, it really does contain "\u003C".  Use a hex viewer as an alternative oracle.  Chrome is a bucket of bugs lately, so try another browser.  But high odds that you need to contact the web site owner to get ahead.